# ORACLE 11g Trigger

Tags: oracle11g, triggers

I am testing the trigger named, "tulockout" listed below, with this alter statement..."alter user testuser account lock;" to see if the trigger log a record of what happened in table, "log_table_changes".
However, certain values are not accurately logging into the table, "log_table_changes". To be specific v_dusr.start_dt is returning NULL when the trigger, "tulockout" fires off after I execute "alter user testuser account lock;" statement.

I am not certain as to why. Can you please assist? 
How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

```
create or replace trigger tulockout 
after alter on schema 

declare

cursor v_abc is
    select du.username, max(us.start_dt)
    from dba_users du, user_session us, users_info ui
    where ui.db_user_name = du.username
      and ui.db_user_name = us.user_name
      and ui.db_user_name = ora_login_user;

v_dusr  v_abc%ROWTYPE; 

begin

  if(ora_sysevent = 'ALTER' and v_dusr.username = ora_dict_obj_name and
v_dusr.account_status = 'LOCKED') then

  insert into log_table_changes(username,
                                lastlogin_date,
                                notes,
                                execute_date,
                                script_name
                               ) 
                         values(
                                v_dusr.username,
                                v_dusr.start_dt,
                                ora_dict_obj_type||', '||
                                ora_dict_obj_name||' has been locked out.',
                                sysdate,
                                ora_sysevent
                               );
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a cursor, and a record based on that; but you don't ever execute the cursor query or populate the variable.

Your cursor query is currently missing a group-by clause so will error when run, because of the aggregate function. You don't really need to include the user name in the select list though, as you already know that value. You are, though, later referring to the `v_duser.account_status` field, which doesn't exist in your cursor query/rowtype, so you need to add (and group by) that too.

The trigger also needs to be at database, not schema, level; and unless you intend to record who performed the alter command, you don't ned to refer to `ora_login_user` - looking *that* user's status up doesn't seem very helpful.

You don't really need a cursor at all; a select-into would do, something like (assuming there will always be a row returned from the joins to your user_session and users_info tables; which implies they store the username in the same case as dba_users does - although I'm not sure why you are joining to users_info at all?):

```
create or replace trigger tulockout 
after alter on database
declare    
  v_start_dt user_session.start_dt%TYPE;
  v_account_status dba_users.account_status%TYPE;
begin   
  select du.account_status, max(us.start_dt)
  into v_account_status, v_start_dt
  from dba_users du
  join user_session us on us.db_user_name = du.username
  -- join not needed?
  -- join users_info ui on ui.db_user_name = us.user_name
  where du.username = ora_dict_obj_name
  group by du.account_status;

  if(ora_sysevent = 'ALTER' and ora_dict_obj_type = 'USER'
      and v_account_status = 'LOCKED') then
    insert ...
```

and then use those date and status variables and `ora_dict_obj_name`(the user that was altered) in the insert.

I've also switched to modern join syntax, and tweaked the conditions a bit.

Untested, but should give you the idea.

You could make it even easier by doing a single `insert ... select` against those tables, removing the need for local variables.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tested your answer but nothings been added to "log_table_changes" table. Do I have "create or replace trigger tulockout 
after alter on schema" correct because the trigger should work off dba_users table status_Account column change from OPEN to LOCKED.

Comment: Your question implies the trigger was working, though insertiing some null values; but looking at it againt I don't think it can have been. I think it has to be a database trigger, not schema? And the two ora_ variables will only match if a user locks their own account - I think... can't test at the moment.